# How to implement combination collapse/expand sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wonder how to implement combination of hide/show and collapse/expand side bar exactly like [**this**](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=conquer) sample.

There will be icons showing when the side bar collapse.

[image]

perhaps it is implemented using jQuery, CSS and HTML, please advise how can I do that, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can via css and for modern browser only, set something with pseudo :checked .

http://jsfiddle.net/T6kG9/1/
It can be useful while working on it , JavaScript should take over :)

```
<nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggleexpand" />
    <label for="toggleexpand"><span>></span>

    </label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div>div</div>
```

```
nav {
    float:left;
}
input {
    position:fixed;
    left:-9999px;
}
label {
    text-align:right;
    display:block;
}
label span {
    background:gray;
    padding:0 0.25em;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    width:20px;
    padding:0;
    list-syle-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 1px;
}
:checked ~ ul li {
    width:250px!important;
}
:checked + label span {
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
div {
    min-height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of jQuery, CSS, and HTML. It is a slight tweak on a design pattern commonly referred to as "Off-Canvas Navigation" or just "Off-Canvas".

I would begin by reading [this Smashing Mag walkthrough](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/) and then modifying what you learn there to fit this demo.